# ASK sql substring for version of value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i had query for update the version of my value, here the code

```
DECLARE @inParam AS VARCHAR(50) = '80003689_CST_20120118'
DECLARE @file_extension varchar(50)='.xlsx'
DECLARE @lastVer AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @nextVer AS INT 
DECLARE @combine AS VARCHAR(50) 

SELECT @lastVer = MAX([File_Name]) 
  FROM dbo.Uploaded_File 
 WHERE [File_Name] LIKE @inParam+'%'

SELECT @nextVer = CAST(SUBSTRING(@lastVer,LEN(@inParam) + 6, 1) AS INT) + 1

SELECT @combine = @inParam + '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @nextVer) + ')' + @file_extension

SELECT @lastVer, @nextVer, @combine
```

the problem is when the value `80003689_CST_20120118(1)`, its not updated the version, the result i had `80003689_CST_20120118(1)(1)`...

but i wanted the result become `80003689_CST_20120118(2)`.

so if i had same value it will become :

```
80003689_CST_20120118
80003689_CST_20120118(1)
80003689_CST_20120118(2)
```

etc

Answered by @Dimitri..
but i can't mark his answered.. its givin error page on me...
thanks dimitri

Comment: Why don't you store the "root name" and the number in separate columns (store 0 for the first use of the name). It'd be a far simpler query (wouldn't require magic string manipulation). OTOH, if you're going to stick with strings - where did "+ 6" come from for the substring operation?

Comment: Storing the root name would also benefit by avoiding having to use `LIKE` with your input parameter. Were you aware that a row containing `'80003689ACSTA20120118'` would be a match for your current query (since `_` is a wildcard for `LIKE`)?

Comment: i had error when i put + 2

the case is when the first value has added = 80003689_CST_20120118.xlsx

and i added again the value 80003689_CST_20120118.xlsx

its given error

cannot convert 'x' to int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it works now:

```
DECLARE @inParam AS VARCHAR(50) = '80003689_CST_20120118'
declare @file_extension varchar(50)='.xlsx'
DECLARE @lastVer AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @nextVer AS INT 
DECLARE @combine AS VARCHAR(50) 

SELECT @lastVer = MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING([File_Name], LEN(@inParam)+2, LEN([File_Name]) - LEN(@inParam) - 2) AS INT))
FROM dbo.Uploaded_File 
WHERE [File_Name] LIKE @inParam+'(%)'

SELECT @nextVer = ISNULL(@lastVer, 0) + 1
SELECT @combine =  @inParam + '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @nextVer) + ')' + @file_extension
SELECT @lastVer,@nextVer,@combine
```

Comment: @dimitry its not working for get version (2) (3) ect

when i add the same value 80003689_CST_20120118

the result is right = 80003689_CST_20120118(1)

but when i added again value 80003689_CST_20120118

its given result same = 80003689_CST_20120118(1)

but i wanted the result of version will growth if i added same value

80003689_CST_20120118

80003689_CST_20120118(1)

80003689_CST_20120118(2)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my test snippet (it doesn't require db table). Can you update to it to reproduce the error?

```
DECLARE @inParam AS VARCHAR(50) = '80003689_CST_20120118'
declare @file_extension varchar(50)='.xlsx'
DECLARE @lastVer AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @nextVer AS INT 
DECLARE @combine AS VARCHAR(50) 

create table #Uploaded_File ( [File_Name] varchar(max) )
insert into #Uploaded_File values( @inParam + '(3)' )
insert into #Uploaded_File values( @inParam + '(22)' )
insert into #Uploaded_File values( @inParam + '(1)' )
insert into #Uploaded_File values( @inParam + '(50)' )

SELECT @lastVer = MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING([File_Name], LEN(@inParam)+2, LEN([File_Name]) - LEN(@inParam) - 2) AS INT))
FROM #Uploaded_File 
WHERE [File_Name] LIKE @inParam+'(%)'

SELECT @nextVer = ISNULL(@lastVer, 0) + 1
SELECT @combine =  @inParam + '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @nextVer) + ')' + @file_extension
SELECT @lastVer,@nextVer,@combine

drop table #Uploaded_File
```